# How to set SCNView camera from ARFrame camera?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I created a SCNView in ViewController, and I have an ARFrame information, how do I set the SCNView camera node so that it is the same as the ARFrame camera ？ I don't want to use ARSCNView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARSession can be run as standalone entity (it must not necessarily be connected to a view). Use the following code to get what you expect:

```
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneKitView: SCNView!
    let session = ARSession()
    var arCameraTransform: simd_float4x4?
    let scnCamera = SCNNode()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        sceneKitView.scene = SCNScene()
        sceneKitView.backgroundColor = .black
        
        let cylinder = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.1, height: 1)
        cylinder.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: cylinder)
        node.position.z = -0.75
        sceneKitView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        
        scnCamera.camera = SCNCamera()
        sceneKitView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(scnCamera)
        
        self.session.delegate = self
        self.session.run(ARWorldTrackingConfiguration())
    }
}
```

...

```
extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

        self.arCameraTransform = frame.camera.transform            
        scnCamera.simdTransform = self.arCameraTransform!   
        print(sceneKitView.pointOfView?.simdTransform.columns.3 as Any)
    }
}
```

P.S.

This works for `.landscape` orientation...

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i want